Xcode failed to upload on Testflight: You do not have required role or permission to perform an operation
From the last night I started getting this error when trying to upload to Testflight:
You do not have required role or permission to perform an operation.
Everything was fine few days ago.

Happens on Xcode 15.2 and Xcode 15.4
The only changes in the code are importing Firebase packages
My developer account is valid
There are no licences to accept
This app was successfully released to App Store last week
I have tried restarting Xcode, cleaning, deleting derived data, removing my developer account from Xcode and adding it again, nothing helped.

Some logs:
2024-10-05 09:32:49.460 DEBUG: [ContentDelivery.Uploader] REQUEST CREATE CONTAINER (ASSET_UPLOAD): received status code 403; forbidden.
2024-10-05 09:32:49.460 ERROR: [ContentDelivery.Uploader] Failed to create a build ID.
2024-10-05 09:32:49.460 ERROR: [ContentDelivery.Uploader] You do not have required role or permission to perform an operation (403) You do not have required role or permission to perform an operation. (ID: ebb3bfb6-9bbe-4234-bf19-ba607513d9c5)


Try logging in to App Store Connect snd going to Users & Access (one of the options in the top menu), then check the roles for the account you are using. I would expect you need to be the account holder or have the role Developer. If you are not able to do this check either, then whoever manages the users in your team needs to do it.

@BenzyNeez I am an account holder of the account.

OK, so try going to Settings > Accounts in Xcode and check that there are no errors.

@BenzyNeez I have already mentioned in the description that I have reseted that.

@BenzyNeez solved, thanks for trying to help. I have provided a solution in the answer.

I finally found a solution, this seems like an Xcode bug.
TLDR: I have removed another developer account from Xcode.
The thing is that for years I had two Apple developer accounts added to Xcode, one private, one business. I regularly published new versions of many applications on Testflight/App Store.
Only a few days ago I had a problem with publishing my own applications using my own account.
The solution was to remove the business account from Xcode > Settings > Accounts.After that, the build passed on the first try.
Later I added again my business account in Xcode and tried to publish my own app, and it was published successfully. Looks like that Xcode was trying to upload the build with wrong account, for some reason.

A version of this worked for me. I had to delete all other accounts except the one I wanted it to be signed with, restart Xcode, and then rebuild and resubmit to get it to work.
